# Avoid Using setState On componentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs, redux, react-redux

**Requirements**

I have a list of links. Every link has an unique URL through an ID. Every link should open or update a window. Only one window should be open at any time, no multiple windows

**Solution**

```
import React from 'react';

let PopUp = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        id: React.PropTypes.string
    },

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            id: null,
            popUp: null
        };
    },

    componentDidUpdate: function() {
        let url = 'http://test.com/' + this.props.id;

        if(this.state.popUp) {
            this.state.popUp.close();
        }

        this.setState({
            popUp: window.open(url, '_blank'),
            id: this.props.id
        });
    },

    shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
        //If no id
        if(!nextProps.id) {
            return false;
        }

        //If same id and open window
        if(nextProps.id === nextState.id && nextState.popUp && !nextState.popUp.closed) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    },

    render: function() {
        return null;
    }
});

export default PopUp;
```

This works. But the problem with this is that I have to use **setState** inside **componentDidUpdate**. This will cause another loop through the life cycle.

Can this be avoided? Is there a better solution? Should I use a global [variable](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/where-do-i-belong-a-guide-to-saving-react-component-data-in-state-store-static-and-this-c49b335e2a00#3c46) or the [context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html)?

Thanks

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` instea of `componentDidUpdate`

Comment: Good idea, thanks!